# Performance diference between Hashs and Pattern

Tags: redis

Let's say I need to store some data for a customer for every product they view.
Additionally, I need to be able to delete all of a customer's keys at once when the customer updates any information.
For this purpose, I am considering using Redis patterns, where the key would be in the format of ${customer-id}:${product-id}.
By using the pattern ${customer-id}:*, I can find and delete all the keys.
However, I am also aware that I could use a Hash with the ${customer-id} as the main key and the ${product-id} as a subkey, with the corresponding data as the subkey's value. If I need to retrieve all the subkeys, I would use HGetAll instead of a pattern.

Is there any performance difference between using hashes or patterns in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, you should use HASH.

If your data set is large, it's slow to `SCAN` and delete all keys matching a pattern (Also NOTE: it's BAD to use the `KEYS` command).

With hash, you can remove the whole customer info with `UNLINK`, which is fast and do not block Redis. When you need to get all items belonging to the customer, and there're lots of items, you'd better use `HSCAN` instead of `HGETALL`, since the latter might block Redis.